# Multitouch drag and drop without ScatterItem

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, pixelsense

Is there any other way to do a multitouch drag and drop operation in WPF other than using SurfaceDragDrop? I'm currently using this as reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957380.aspx

The problem I have with SurfaceDragDrop:

1. It converts everything into a scatter item, which looks somewhat weird in my application context
2. The width and height of the dragged item seems to depend on where it's being dragged from - I can only drag it from a rather small area, but I need a bigger preview. Specifying the source as something bigger (i.e. the parent element) results either in a element thats too big or (/and) an element that's not under the touchpoint